# Timer that keeps counting when navigating away from page

Tags: javascript

I have a timer that counts down once a specific page is visited. I need this timer to keep counting even if someone goes to a different page, and maintain the time counted to display it on the screen when they return to the original page where it was triggered.

The code I have in place is

```
<script>
function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays)
{
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(d.getTime()+(exdays*24*60*60*1000));
var expires = "expires="+d.toGMTString();
document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}
function getCookie(cname)
{
var name = cname + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) 
{
var c = ca[i].trim();
if (c.indexOf(name)==0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
}
return "";
}

//check existing cookie
cook=getCookie("test9_cookie");

if(cook==""){
//cookie not found, so set seconds=60
var seconds = '<?php echo OFFERTIME ?>';
}else{
seconds = cook;
console.log(cook);
}

// init var
var timeout = 0;
// end init var
function secondPassed() {
var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30)/60);
var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
    remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds; 
}
//store seconds to cookie
setCookie("test9_cookie",seconds,1); //here 1 is expiry days
document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" +    remainingSeconds;
if (seconds == 0) {
    clearInterval(countdownTimer);
    timeout = 1;
    sessionStorage.setItem('nothanks', 1);
  document.getElementById('timed-over').style.display = "block";
  $("#timed-over").delay(4800).fadeOut(300);
  document.getElementById('timed-container').style.display = "none";

} else {    
    seconds--;
}
}

var countdownTimer = setInterval(secondPassed, 1000);

//localStorage.removeItem('timedpid') //to delete localstorage during testing
function checktaken(){
if(timeout===1) {
//do nothing as expired
}else if(localStorage.getItem('timedpid')) {
   var storedpid = localStorage.getItem('timedpid')
   var currentpid =<?php echo json_encode($time_limited_pid); ?>;
   if (storedpid !== currentpid) {
        var showOffer = document.querySelector("#timed-container");
        showOffer.style.display = "block";
   }
   }else if(sessionStorage.getItem('nothanks')) {
   // do nothing as offer not wanted 
   }else{
    var showOffer = document.querySelector("#timed-container");
    showOffer.style.display = "block";
   }
}
setInterval('checktaken()',1); 
</script>
```

Is there any way to make the original code keep counting when the page the script is on is navigated away from?

If not, a solution would be to move part of the script to the header and have it only load when on a specific page. Doing this would mean having to pass a var from the script in the header, to a script in a different file. I'm not too clued up on javascript and haven't had any luck sharing variables across multiple pages before.

Answer (score 2):

Stuff the start time into the cookie (or local storage, anything permanent) and use the difference between that start time and the current time for your timer.